# Can't SSH into raspberry pi after being inactive for a while

Tags: ssh, pi-3b+

Alright, so, I've recently set up the Raspbian OS on the raspberry pi 3b, and I can ssh into it normally. Although, if I leave the pi inactive for a while and don't do anything with it, I'm unable to ssh into it after a few minutes (around 30 minutes).

```
ssh pi@192.168.0.16
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset
```

And yes, that is the correct IP.

Comment: I take it you have no way of connecting a keyboard and monitor to the pi to see what's going on

Comment: I do. Although, after around 30 minutes of no interaction with my raspberry pi, the monitor doesn't display anything at all. Only way to get it back to normal is to restart the pi.

Comment: I don't know if it will be any help, but I do remember having this exact same issue a while back with a Pi 3A and I remember after doing a series of updates and keeping the system up to date the problem went away. Again, it has been a while (3-4 years) since I encounter this and I cannot remember configuring anything power-management specific, I can only vouch for keeping the system updated. Out of curiosity, are you using an approved Pi 3 power adapter or equivalent with 5V 2.5-3.0A rating?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/115929/ssh-connection-reset-immediately-after-conncting) and [this one too](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334437/ssh-connection-reset-after-idle-for-some-time)